# bash script: [: ==: unary operator expected even though I'm almost sure my conditional syntax is right

Tags: bash, unix

Hello everyone I seem to be stuck on the "elif [ $1 == 0 ]" part of my script.

The purpose of this conditional statement is to exit if the user did not pass an argument to my script.

(if the user simply runs "sh safe_rm" instead of "sh safe_rm filename which is the intended behavior)

I'm still in the early stages of this script so it doesn't do anything so far, but I want to get the conditionals out of the way first, but I can't find out what I did wrong with elif [ $1 == 0 ] . I have also tried elif [ $1 -eq 0 ]   and elif [ $1 == '' ] and none of them seem to be working

```
   # This checks whether the  $HOME/deleted/ exists. If it does not exist, it will get created. If it exists, nothing happens.
if [ ! -d $HOME/deleted/ ]
        then
                echo "/deleted/ directory does not exist. Creating it..."
                mkdir $HOME/deleted/
        else
        echo "Directory /Deleted/ already exists. Continuing..."
fi
# The conditional statements below check if the argument passed is a directory, or if it does not exist, or if nothing has been passed.
# All 3 cases will cause the program to quit since there is nothing to be done. The user needs to provide a file that exists.
if [ ! -e $1 ]
        then
                echo "File does not exist!"
                exit 1
elif [ $1 == 0 ]   #<---problem here I have also tried elif [ $1 -eq 0 ] and elif [ $1 == '' ]
        then
                echo "No filename has been provided!"
                exit 1
elif [ -d $1 ]
        then
                echo "This is a directory, not a file!"
                exit 1
elif [ $1 == 'safe_rm' ]
        then
                echo "Attempting to delete safe_rm. Operation aborted."
                exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `[` does not have a `==` operator and -eq is an arithmetic operator so won't work on a filename. Please show what the input and output of your program is.

Comment: I've originally tried [ $1 -eq 0 ] but it's the same error, so I started trying different things to no avail

Comment: What is `$1` supposed to be, and are you sure it has a value?

Comment: $1 is the argument the user passes to my script. It should be a filename that is to be deleted.

I have been able to test it successfully in the cases where a user provides a directory instead of a file, or if the user provides a file that does not exist, or even if the user tries to pass my own script as a filename to be deleted

Comment: `man test` to see all the things you can test with `[`. They include `-d` and `-f`. Quote your variables; without an argument, `"$1"` is an empty string, whereas `$1` provides nothing to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test if the user passed no argument, the statement should be:

```
...
elif [ $# -eq 0 ]
...
```

Comment: even with elif [ $1 -eq 0 ] I am getting the same error. I have already tried  elif [ $1 -eq 0 ] ,  elif [ $1 == 0 ] , and  elif [ $1 == '' ] without sucess:

Comment: nevermind. i was able to solve this by using "elif [ -z $1 ]

This correctly gave me the result I wanted

Comment: @stfudonny You misread my reply, I didn't used `$1` but `$#`.The former is the first argument, the latter is the number of arguments. `-z $1` is not the best way to check if no argument was passed.

Comment: Sorry about that I did not know what $# was.
Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: ...or even `elif (( $# == 0 ))`

Answer (score 2):

You should quote your arguments. In your case, when `$1` is not set, the test expands to `[ == 0 ]`, which is syntactically incorrect.

`[ "$1" == 0 ]` however would resolve to `[ "" == 0 ]`, which is syntactically correct and return false.

It's still not what you want obviously, but jlliagre's answer provides that.

Comment: For bash, using `[[]]` instead would also be an option. As a builtin, it "knows" about `$1` even if it turns out empty.